# Did Scala case class annotations change in 2.10?

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-2.10

In Scala 2.9 I would annotate a case class using the `import scala.annotation.target.field`:

```
case class UserAuth(
  @(JsonProperty@field)("email")
  val email: String,

  @(JsonProperty@field)("password")
  val password: String
)
```

In 2.10 I go to compile a class, and I need to use `import scala.annotation.meta.field` but suddenly it's throwing compiler errors like crazy. Is this the proper usage of the Scala case class annotation or can I revert back to simple `@JsonProperty("email")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it was some sort of weird bug in the compiler, but I can confirm that the syntax `@(JsonProperty@field)("email")` using `import scala.annotation.meta.field` does work.

Looks like classes weren't loading properly and a simple `sbt clean` fixed the issue. Will file a bug if the problem persists.